# Java/JSP library to render composite objects as HTML?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

Is there an existing open-source Java or JSTL tag library that will render the contents of a passed-in object as HTML content?   I'm thinking of an object like this:

```
Object Cat {
    String name;
    Integer age;
    String color;
    Coat coat;  // Enum: LONG/MEDIUM/SHORT
}
```

Ideally you could pass in a Cat object and get back an HTML representation of the object's contents, perhaps with clickable links to expand/collapse content:

```
<H1>Object Type: Cat </H1>
<ul>
    <li><span>name</span><span>"Fluffy"</span></li>
    <li><span>age</span><span> 9</span></li>
    <li><span>color</span><span> "Tabby"</span></li>
    <li><span>coat</span><span> LONG</span></li>
</ul>
```

Seems like something that someone might have already written.  I would hate to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html) library. It converts your java code to xml. Using XSLT, you can convert your xml to html format (Simple xml transformation using xslt is [here](http://xstream.codehaus.org/manual-tweaking-output.html) - XML Transformations).

Comment: This is the closest solution so far - still hoping for something without the intermediate XML step...

Answer (score 0):

When reinventing the wheel is easier than going to the store and buying one, why not?  Here's a simplified JSP (assumes you already have your `Cat` in the variable `cat`):

```
<H1>Object Type: Cat </H1>
<ul>
    <li><span>name</span><span>"<%=cat.name%>"</span></li>
    <li><span>age</span><span> <%=cat.age%></span></li>
    <li><span>color</span><span> "<%=cat.color%>"</span></li>
    <li><span>coat</span><span> <%=cat.coat%></span></li>
</ul>
```

If you want to generify it for any object, use reflection to iterate through your properties and get them dynamically, as well as the object type.